# Calculate salary by year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the salary of employees for each year. Let's say if an employee is in company for 1.5 years since July 2016 than I want to show the records in 2 rows like salary of 2016 and 2017 separately. If monthly salary is `20000` so for `18 months` this is how result should be displayed.

```
EmpID  Year   MonthlySalary  YearlySalary  TotalSalary
1      2016   20000          120000        120000 (because was hired in jul)
1      2017   20000          240000        360000
2      2017   18000          216000        216000
```

I have a query that calculates the salary per month, years and total salary as well. I am calculating the total salary using months.

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeInfo (
EmpID Int,
FirstName Varchar(25),
LastName Varchar(25),
MonthlySalary Int,
DOJ Date);


INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo VALUES (1, 'Ahmad', 'Usman', '20000', '2016-06-01');
INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo VALUES (2, 'Erick', 'Ortiz', '18000', '2017-01-01');


SELECT [EmployeeName] = [EI].[FirstName] + ' ' + [EI].[LastName],
       [EI].[DOJ],
       [MonthlySalary] = [EI].MonthlySalary,
       [EXPERIENCE] = ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(YEAR, [DOJ], Getdate())) ),
       [TotalSalary] = ( ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(MONTH, [DOJ], Getdate())) ) * ( Isnull(NULL, [EI].MonthlySalary) ) )
FROM   [EmployeeInfo] [EI]
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: @Pரதீப் The expected output is at the start of the post.

Comment: which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: Till which year this needs to calculated  ?

Comment: I want to calculate for all years. Please read the description. If the employee was hired in 2016 then I want to calculate for 2016's salary and 2017's salary separately.

Comment: Why you want to calculate only till 2017 ? If it is always 2 years then why empid 2 is not calculated till 2018 ?

Comment: Because 2018's month is not completed yet. When January's pay will be given then the rows will automatically become 3 2016, 2017 and 2018.

Comment: The idea is to calculate the salary of the employee for each year. If the year is not completed than it should be calculated for the months that have employee been paid for.

Comment: What if salary has changed? How it will be represented in your table?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'd be moving next. I am curious about that part too but I wanted to solve this part first.

Comment: No need to divide question in that way. Provide some sample data that display salary change

Comment: I have another table names GlobalEmployement in which I am storing the date along with the previous salary of the employee so I think I'll be able to get the salary difference from that table. But at the moment I am not worried about that part but this one instead because that once still need some modifications to be made.

Comment: What's your server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a calendar table to do this, I have used recursive cte to generate the dates.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, MonthlySalary, DOJ, cntr = 1, SalaryMonth = DOJ
         FROM   EmployeeInfo
         UNION ALL
         SELECT e.EmpID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.MonthlySalary, e.DOJ, cntr = cntr + 1, Dateadd(month, cntr, e.DOJ)
         FROM   cte c
                JOIN EmployeeInfo e
                  ON c.EmpID = e.EmpID
         WHERE  Dateadd(month, cntr, e.DOJ) < DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(Getdate())),Getdate()))
SELECT EmpID,
       [Year] = Year(SalaryMonth),
       MonthlySalary,
       YearlySalary = Sum(MonthlySalary),
       TotalSalary = Sum(Sum(MonthlySalary)) OVER(partition BY EmpID ORDER BY Year(SalaryMonth))
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY EmpID, Year(SalaryMonth), MonthlySalary 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: What if I have to add another column ?
I'm trying to link department table and designation table with employee info but it is not letting me

Comment: Department's column name is FullName and Employee info have dept code as foreign key and department table have dptid as PK

Comment: Also what if at some point the salary of an employee changes. How can I handle it ?

Comment: @Doonie Darkoo Please ask a new question with relevant details

Answer (score 1):

Try Recursive CTE. Like this

```
 ;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmpId,
        EmpYr = YEAR(DOJ),
        Month = 12-CASE WHEN MONTH(DOJ) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE MONTH(DOJ) END,
        MonthlySalary,
        YearlySalary = MonthlySalary*(12-CASE WHEN MONTH(DOJ) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE MONTH(DOJ) END),
        TotalSal = MonthlySalary*(12-CASE WHEN MONTH(DOJ) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE MONTH(DOJ) END)
        FROM EmployeeInfo

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        EmpId,
        EmpYr = EmpYr+1,
        Month = 12,
        MonthlySalary,
        YearlySalary = MonthlySalary*
                                (
                                  CASE WHEN EmpYr = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                                        THEN MONTH(GETDATE())
                                      ELSE 12 END
                                 ),
        TotalSal = TotalSal+(MonthlySalary*
                                (
                                  CASE WHEN EmpYr = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                                        THEN MONTH(GETDATE())
                                      ELSE 12 END
                                 ))
        FROM CTE
            WHERE EmpYr < YEAR(GETDATE())
)
SELECT
  EmpId,
  EmpYr,
  MonthlySalary,
  YearlySalary,
  TotalSalary = TotalSal
  FROM CTE
    ORDER BY EmpId
```

My Result

[image]

Check the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0dd3/12)

Comment: I added for current year but it gave me the salary of this year too which is not true because if there's been only a month of current year than why it should give the whole years pay ?

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo I have updated the Answer as well as the Demo in SqlFiddle. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
with sy as (
      Select EmpId, year(DOJ) cyear, FirstName+' '+LastName AS EmployeeName, 
      avg(MonthlySalary) MonthlySalary, sum(MonthlySalary) YearlySalary, avg(MonthlySalary)*12 TotalSalary
     FROM EmployeeInfo
     group by year(DOJ),FirstName+' '+LastName, EmpID
    )
select sy1.EmpId, sy1.cyear, sy1.EmployeeName, sy1.MonthlySalary MonthlySalary, sy1.YearlySalary, sum(sy2.YearlySalary) TotalSalary from
sy sy1, sy sy2
where sy1.EmpId = sy2.EmpId and sy1.EmployeeName = sy2.EmployeeName and sy1.cyear >= sy2.cyear 
group by sy1.EmpId, sy1.cyear, sy1.EmployeeName, sy1.YearlySalary,sy1.MonthlySalary
```

(EmpId added)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple reference table and then conduct the join.

Note: "Sum (....) OVER (....)"  only works in SQL Server version 2012 or later.

```
WITH REF ( YY ) AS (
    SELECT 2017  --OR USE THE LATEST YEAR PREFERRED.
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  YY - 1
    FROM REF
    WHERE REF.YY > 1950 -- SET THE EARLIEST YEAR
)
SELECT 
    EI.EmpID,
    REF.YY AS [Year],
    EI.MonthlySalary,
    CASE WHEN REF.YY = YEAR(DOJ) THEN MonthlySalary*(13-MONTH(DOJ))
        ELSE MonthlySalary * 12 END AS YearlySalary,
    SUM (CASE WHEN REF.YY = YEAR(DOJ) THEN MonthlySalary*(13-MONTH(DOJ))
        ELSE MonthlySalary * 12 END ) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPID ORDER BY REF.YY) TotalSalary
    FROM [EmployeeInfo] [EI]
JOIN
    REF
ON
    YEAR(DOJ) <= YY
ORDER BY 
    EI.EMPID, REF.YY
;
```